# Difference between soci::i_ok and soci::i_null

Tags: c++, database, soci

I could not find an explanation of the soci::i_ok and soci::i_null constants. They are mentioned in this [page](http://soci.sourceforge.net/doc/3.2/reference.html) as possible states of data, but their exact meaning is not defined.

I was wondering if soci::i_ok is true does it mean that the data is not null?

```
(soci::i_ok == indicatorX) == (soci::i_null != indicatorX)  ---?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some explanation to the question on this page under the topic: [Handling nulls and other conditions](http://soci.sourceforge.net/doc/3.2/exchange.html). Sharing it here, for the benefit of the community.

Based on the document, `soci::i_ok` indicates that the value is returned without any error and it contains a not null value. And `soci::i_null` means that the value is null, because the column contained a null value.

So, yeah, `(soci::i_ok == indicatorX)` means, `(soci::i_null != indicatorX)` and there are no fetch errors. As `soci::i_ok` encompasses the use of `soci::i_null` I guess the two constants were placed for different reasons (like if you want an explicit null check).